# Disable javascript onclick when JSF validation fails

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I have simple JSF form and onclick event inside submit button (google analytics event tracking). Is it posible to somehow disable onclick event when jsf validation fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. The onclick is fired *before* the request is sent to server. You basically want to fire it *after* the response has returned with a successful outcome.

There are several ways to achieve this:

- Perform validation in JavaScript instead (not recommended).
- Send tracking request from inside JSF bean's action method instead.
- Send tracking request inside a (conditionally rendered) `<script>` element on result page instead.

Comment: Can you say more about 2? Is it possible to run javascript inside JSF method?!?

Comment: No, that is what I meant with 3. With 2 I just meant to use Java instead of JavaScript.